# Using Import-CSV to make HTTP Request

Tags: powershell, http-request

Wonder if anyone can help. I'm trying to use powershell to import a list of domains and generate a HTTP request for each of them. Currently I've got this far:

```html
$csvFilename = "C:\Sites\sites.csv" 
$csv = Import-Csv $csvFilename -Header @("url") |
foreach {

   $HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create('$csv')

   $HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()

   $HTTP_Status = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode

If ($HTTP_Status -eq 200) { 
    Write-Host "Site is OK!" 
}
Else {
    Write-Host "The Site may be down, please check!"
}

$HTTP_Response.Close()

}
```

I'm not sure why but the 'Create()' statement won't pick up the URL. Any ideas?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

inside the foreach loop, you can access the current element with the automatic variable `$_`

so replace this line `$HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create('$csv')`
by
`$HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("$_")`

but before as create method is waiting for a string,you will have to expand your url property (otherwise you get a pscustomObject not a string) :
`Import-Csv c:\temp\urls.csv -Header "url" |select -expand url |%{ [System.Net.Webrequest]::Create("$_")}`

Comment: Using an automatic variable throws "Cannot find an overload for "Create" and the argument count: "1"", could possibly be the CSV file so I may have to start there

Comment: if you're running ps v3 try `invoke-webrequest($_)`

Comment: thanks for your help, I just didn't have my variables set right.

Used the following and it's working now: 
foreach ($row in $csv) {

write-host $row

$url = $row.url